# Want to display an image onto a view but in semicurve shape

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, uiimageview

I want to display an image in iPhone application on the whole screen but with a semi curve shape.
The image should start from the corner touching and ends on touching the another corner. I don't have an idea to make this can anyone help me please.
This image table is semi curved but image should be displayed on semi curved shape

[image: This image table is semi curved but image should be displayed on semi curved shape]

Comment: You mean you want your UIView to be semi curved? Why not just use the alpha?

Comment: By using alpha it not looks semi curve..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Changing the image to be curvical or playing with images can be achieved Using CALayer. Every imageView has a layer over it. Use it to show the effect. The effect you wanted on your table image can be acheived through this code:-

```
-(void) viewDidLoad{

   [self paperCurlShadowImage];
}

-(void) paperCurlShadowImage{

        imgView = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:image];
        imgView.frame=CGRectMake(0, 0, image.size.width, image.size.height);


        [self.view addSubview:imgView];

        imgView.layer.shadowColor = [UIColor blackColor].CGColor;
        imgView.layer.shadowOpacity = 0.7f;
        imgView.layer.shadowOffset = CGSizeMake(10.0f, 10.0f);
        imgView.layer.shadowRadius = 2.0f;
        imgView.layer.masksToBounds = NO;


        imgView.layer.shadowPath = [self renderPaperCurl:imgView];
        [imgView release];
```

}

```
- (CGPathRef)renderPaperCurl:(UIView*)imgView1 {
    CGSize size = imgView1.bounds.size;
    CGFloat curlFactor = 15.0f;
    CGFloat shadowDepth = 5.0f;

    UIBezierPath *path = [UIBezierPath bezierPath];
    [path moveToPoint:CGPointMake(0.0f, 0.0f)];
    [path addLineToPoint:CGPointMake(size.width, 0.0f)];
    [path addLineToPoint:CGPointMake(size.width, size.height + shadowDepth)];
    [path addCurveToPoint:CGPointMake(0.0f, size.height + shadowDepth)
            controlPoint1:CGPointMake(size.width - curlFactor, size.height + shadowDepth - curlFactor)
            controlPoint2:CGPointMake(curlFactor, size.height + shadowDepth - curlFactor)];

    return path.CGPath;
}
```

Comment: imgView.layer.shadowColor = [UIColor blackColor].CGColor;
 imgView.layer.shadowOpacity = 0.7f;
 imgView.layer.shadowOffset = CGSizeMake(10.0f, 10.0f);
 imgView.layer.shadowRadius = 2.0f;
 imgView.layer.masksToBounds = NO;
 
 
 imgView.layer.shadowPath = [self renderPaperCurl:imgView];

Comment: These lines are showing error of "Accessing unknown shadowColor component of a property. same for all lines with different name. please help me out

Comment: Do you have imported the quartzCore,CoreGraphics both the  framework in your Project?